# How to get selected radio button values?

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I need get the selected radio button values. Radio button name is `is_external`

**test.html**

```
<div class="exter_inter">
    External <input type="radio" name="is_external" value="1" <?php if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status']=='1') echo "checked";?> />
    Internal <input type="radio" name="is_external" value="0"  <?php if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status']=='0') echo "checked";?>  />
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('input:radio').change(function() {      
        var is_external = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();   
        alert("selected values: " + is_external); //Return undefined  

    });
} );
```

Comment: `$("input[name='is_external']:checked").val();`

Comment: Replace `radio` to `is_external` :  `$("input[name='is_external']:checked").val(); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio').change(function() {
    var is_external = $("input[name='is_external']:checked").val();//name is is_external not radio
    alert("selected values: " + is_external); //Return undefined  

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exter_inter">
  External
  <input type="radio" name="is_external" value="1" />Internal
  <input type="radio" name="is_external" value="0" />
</div>
```

Name is `is_external` not `radio`

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="radio" name="user" value="newUser">New User
   <input type="radio" name="user" value="registeredUser">Registered User

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input:radio").change(function () {
            var x = $("input[name='user']:checked").val();
            console.log(x);
         });
    });
```